# $ is not defined - But i can see that it is and is being loaded

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, frameset

I have an odd question.

I am trying to implement some simple logic on some radio buttons and checkboxes on my web application. However, when i attempt to run the application, i am receiving the following error in Firefox:

**ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

**My jQuery:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

alert("Test JS file is loaded");


jQuery('#CTRL').click(function () {

        jQuery('#CTRLDEC').attr('disabled', true);
        jQuery('#OUT').attr('value', 'N');

});

jQuery('#CTRL1').click(function () {

    jQuery('#CTRLDEC').attr('disabled', false);
    jQuery('#OUT').attr('value', 'Y');

});

});
```

When debugging in Firefox, i can see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

And have checked the file exists, is named correctly and contains the plugin code.

As the site is using framesets (old web site that i will soon be getting rid of framesets), i can also see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Is imported again..

Important twice shouldn't cause this issue, should it??

Comment: Are you calling `$(document).ready()` before you reference jquery?

Comment: are you loading jQuery in the right frame?

Comment: Have you tried using a difference source for your JQuery? Try the one here:https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide and see if the issue goes away. If it does, it may mean that your copy is not being loaded correctly/functioning correctly

Comment: What if you change it to `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ .... });` ?

Comment: Oh... Framesets.. I totally read that as frameworks. If jquery is being loaded in one frameset, it still needs to be loaded in a different frameset if that other frameset also needs it (think of each frame as a completely different page). Definitely need to get away from framesets.

Comment: @KevinB -  I was loading my .js file before the plugin - error resolved :) How do you recommend i get of framesets? I need to use HTML/5, javascript and CSS only... Im not fan of handlebars.js

Comment: Most of the functionality they add is replaced by server-side code that does the header and menu includes  on every page.

Comment: @KevinB - do you have any guides or how-to's? Im familiar with ASP.Net Master pages, but HTML equivalents is confusing.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't do it with html at all typically. i'm not familiar with ASP so i wouldn't be much help there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have a conflict with `jQuery`'s global `$`. Make sure you load `jQuery` before you run your main JavaScript, and for good measure, replace:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { ... }
```

...with:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { ... }
```

Comment: +1, especially since he's used `jQuery` instead of `$` everywhere else.

Comment: @jterry - i was loading my .js file before the plugin - error resolved :)